# nodejs express restarts the service after monitoring static resource changes

Tags: node.js, express

I set up some static resources with express

```
import * as express from "express";
const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static("./static"));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

There is an index.html file in the static directory. I want to restart express and refresh the browser after changing index.html

I tried nodemon but not what I want

Comment: JF[Google It!](https://bytearcher.com/articles/refresh-changes-browser-express-livereload-nodemon/)

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly Thank you `livereload` and `connect-livereload` are what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install `livereload` and `connect-livereload`

```
import * as express from "express";
import * as livereload from "livereload";
import * as connectLivereload from "connect-livereload";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const staticpath = "./static";

const liveReloadServer = livereload.createServer();
liveReloadServer.watch(staticpath);

app.use(connectLivereload());
app.use(express.static(staticpath));

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```